# Can classes that use template attributes for loops have those loops unrolled?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

Lets say I have this class:

```
template <int n>
struct collection {
    int data[n];

    int sum() {
        int s = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            s += data[i];
        }
        return s;
    }
};
```

As a performance optimization, it is clearly possible to implement the sum function as follows:

```
int s = 0;
s += data[0]
...
s += data[n - 1]
return s
```

or perhaps even

```
return data[0] + ... + data[n - 1];
```

since n is known during compile time, it can do away with the loop.

Is this something that is already done automatically? Or is there some kind of directive I can give to the compiler? Or impossibru?

Comment: If you are asking whether a compiler could, in principle, do that, then yes, I don't see why not. If you are asking whether your particular compiler does it - then just compile a sample program, inspect the generated assembly and see for yourself.

Comment: A good compiler will do it for small enough values of `n` (e.g. GCC and clang do). I don't know about VS2013 but I'd guess that the same is true.

Comment: g++ is a bit lazy and stop unrolling for `n = 71` while clang goes up to `n = 240`, funny ;) B.T.W, if you initialize `data` with trivial values (such as using `std::iota`), both will compute the sum at compile time for small values of `n`. Cannot test on VS right now but I am pretty sure it will do the same.